# MYSQL query check if user like

Tags: php, mysql

I'm asking for query statement I have two tables 
first table 'posts' :

```
post_id     title    Userid
1           test     1
```

The other table is 'likes'

```
userid  post_id
1       1
```

I need single query to check if user like this photo or not in bulk select my solution is very poor :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE x = x LIMIT 100;
```

and give it foreach and make query for every row :

```
foreach($results as $v)
{
   $data[1] = $v;
   $data[1]['is_like'] = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE userid = 1;
}
```

1 is the already login user id

I need to single query to return post_id,.. etc and filed like is_like

Comment: Please edit your question to add some sample data to the `likes` table, and then add the results you'd like to get from that sample data combined with the data in `posts`. It's hard to tell what you're asking without it. Thanks.

Comment: I have add it, you can check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.post_id,
    p.title,
    IF(l.post_id IS NOT NULL,1,0) as like
FROM posts as p
LEFT JOIN likes as l ON l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.userid = p.userid
WHERE p.Userid = 1
```

If post_id in likes table is available it will return 1 else 0.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `likes` can have only 1 row with the same (user_id,post_id) :

```
SELECT p.* , 
CASE WHEN 
l.id IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE 1
END as is_liked
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.user_id = p.user_id and l.post_id =p.post_id
```

If not (multiple rows in `likes` for a given (user_id,post_id) ) :

```
SELECT p.* , 
CASE WHEN 
l.user_id IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE 1
END as is_liked
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT user_id,post_id FROM likes 
) l ON l.user_id = p.user_id and l.post_id =p.post_id;
```

Or

```
SELECT p.* , 
CASE 
WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM likes l 
  WHERE l.user_id = p.user_id and l.post_id =p.post_id) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as is_liked
FROM posts p
```

**Update**
I hope I got a better understanding of the question now. My assumption : `posts.user_id` is id of user who created post; `like` table stores information about who likes the post. Thus, to check all posts and whether a particular like them  you need (`$login_user_id` should be escaped properly)

```
SELECT p.* , 
CASE 
WHEN  EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM likes l 
  WHERE l.user_id = $login_user_id and l.post_id =p.post_id) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END as is_liked
FROM posts p
```

Comment: Hi, first thank's for your answer
I need to check it for already login user I have variable like 
$login_user_id = 1;
I need to check if this user like post or not for every post in looop

Comment: I expect you did not understand my question my problem is :
I have ($login_user_id) this user is already login now I need to check for every post is this user like it or not,

Comment: @user1920678 : check updated version. Hopefully I understood what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as a single query (untested, of course - you didn't provide much data to use for testing):

```
select 
  p.title, count(l.post_id) 
from 
  `posts` p
inner join 
  `likes` l
on 
  l.userid = p.userid and l.post_id = p.post_id
where 
  p.userid = loggedinuserID
group by 
  p.userid
```

This will give you a count of the total posts the specified user has liked.