# select data from a table and fill specific value from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, node.js, database

I have two tables `discussions` and `votes` that are like this

**discussions**

[image: please see discussions table image]

**votes**

[image: please see votes table image]

that *parentId* in *votes* is *id* in *discussions* table

**but exist a problem**

I want to have a key with name `likeByMe` and want to fill this key when select discussions for specific user.
how can I connect these two tables and fill this value when call one query?

I want something like this

```
select * 
from discussions
```

and fill likeByMe from votes table for any rows by true or false value

Comment: it's hard to understand what you mean.  show some sample data and desired results for that sample data.   ideally edit your question to add (as text, not an image) output of `show create table votes;` and `show create table discussions;` and insert statements for your sample data.

Comment: note:  I have "discussions table" I want to send all rows of discussions table to a client but before that, I want to check if this client liked this row or not. and we should detect it from the votes table that saves discussionId and userId that liked it.

Comment: my question is like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416789/mysql-query-check-if-user-like

Comment: how is your question different than that question?  sample data and results will make it so much clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description, you can use `exists`:

```
select d.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from votes v
                where v.parentid = d.id and v.userid = ?
               )
       ) as likedByMe
from discussions d;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the user you care about.